# spring data solr showcase

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-solr

I am trying to understand the spring data solr showcase project.

https://github.com/christophstrobl/spring-data-solr-showcase

After spending quite a bit of time, I could not find how the productRepository is **implemented** and **injected** in https://github.com/christophstrobl/spring-data-solr-showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/solr/showcase/product/ProductServiceImpl.java

```
@Service class ProductServiceImpl implements ProductService { 
private static final Pattern IGNORED_CHARS_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("\\p{Punct}"); 
private ProductRepository productRepository;


@Autowired
public void setProductRepository(ProductRepository productRepository) {
    this.productRepository = productRepository;
}
```

The ProductRepository is defined as interface (https://github.com/christophstrobl/spring-data-solr-showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/solr/showcase/product/ProductRepository.java) and I did not find any code implementing this interface

```
interface ProductRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<Product, String> {

    @Highlight(prefix = "<b>", postfix = "</b>")
    @Query(fields = { SearchableProductDefinition.ID_FIELD_NAME, 
                      SearchableProductDefinition.NAME_FIELD_NAME,
                      SearchableProductDefinition.PRICE_FIELD_NAME, 
                      SearchableProductDefinition.FEATURES_FIELD_NAME,
                      SearchableProductDefinition.AVAILABLE_FIELD_NAME }, 
           defaultOperator = Operator.AND)
    HighlightPage<Product> findByNameIn(Collection<String> names, Pageable page);

    @Facet(fields = { SearchableProductDefinition.NAME_FIELD_NAME })
    FacetPage<Product> findByNameStartsWith(Collection<String> nameFragments, Pageable pagebale);
}
```

Below is how the spring context is configured: 
https://github.com/christophstrobl/spring-data-solr-showcase/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/solr/showcase/Application.java

If anyone could point me to the direction where this interface is implemented and injected, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The showcase makes use of Spring Data repository abstractions using query derivation from method name. So the infrastructure provided by [Spring Data](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data) and the Solr module take care of creating the required implementations for you. Please have a look at the [Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories) for a more detailed explanation.

The showcase itself is built in a way that allows you to [step through several stages of development](https://github.com/christophstrobl/spring-data-solr-showcase/commits/master) by having a look at the diffs transitioning from one step to the other. So having a look at [Step 2](https://github.com/christophstrobl/spring-data-solr-showcase/commit/3044165aa9ed0e7f62609fa07d71be148a08d304) shows how to make use of [Custom Repository Implementation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations), while [Step 4](https://github.com/christophstrobl/spring-data-solr-showcase/commit/49104de56b35950b4de7570eb8574613da38fed7) demonstractes how to enable Highlighting using `@Highlight`.

Comment: from the horse's mouth... Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

The goal of Spring Data is to reduce the amount of boilerplate coding (means to reduce repetition of code).

For the basic methods like save,find the implementation will provide by spring and spring will create beans(Objetcs) for these interfaces.
 To tell the spring that these are my repositories inside this package, we are writing `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackeges="com.spring.repositories")` or `<jpa:repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories"/>` for JPA repositories

 Foring solr repositores we have to write `@EnableSolrRepositories(basePackages="com.spring.repositories"` or `<solr:repositories base-package="com.acme.repositories" />` Spring will create objetcs for these interfaces, we can inject these interface objetcs using `@Autowire` annotation.

```
Example:
 @Service
 Pulic class SomeService{
     @Autowire
     private SampleRepository;

     /*  @postConstruct annotation is used to execute method just after creating bean 
          and injecting all dependencies by spring*/
     @PostConstruct
     public void postConstruct(){
          System.out.println("SampleRepository implementation class name"+ SampleRepository.getClass());
     }
 }
```

The above example is to see the implementation class of SampleRepository interface (This class is not user defined, it is class given by spring).

For reference documentation link http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/solr/docs/2.0.2.RELEASE/reference/html/.
 Try to read this simple documentation you can get more knowlede on spring-data.